# Automatic node finding for dynamic nodes (dom-repeat) Polymer 1.0

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

In the example below, I want to be able to set the id with the attribute 'first' and select it later with the function '_dummy'. The code below is not working and I have no idea why. I follow the instruction in the [doc](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html#node-finding). Can somebody identify the problem?

```
<dom-module id="my-positions-list">
  <template>

    <div> Employee list: </div>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{employees}}">
        <div id$="{{item.first}}">{{_dummy(item)}}</div> 
        <div>First name: <span>{{item.first}}</span></div>
        <div>Last name: <span>{{item.last}}</span></div>
    </template>

  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-positions-list',
      _dummy: function(item){
        var elem = this.$$("#"+item.first); // returns undifined
        console.log(elem);
      },

      ready: function() {
        this.employees = [
            {first: 'Bob ', last: 'Smith', country: 'united states'},
            {first: 'Sally', last: 'Johnson', country: 'united kingdom'}
        ];
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add employees to the properties with a default value.
And you're selecting a node who is just getting created. You need to wait for your local dom to be ready to use your _dummy function.
Use the ready function to get to the node you want.
And consider proper ids (no capital letter, e.g.).
For these kind of problem you should consult the documentation for polymer lifecycles (https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html)

```
<dom-module id="my-positions-list">
    <template>

        <div> Employee list: </div>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{employees}}">
            <div id="{{item.first}}"></div>
            <div>First name: <span>{{item.first}}</span></div>
            <div>Last name: <span>{{item.last}}</span></div>
        </template>

    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'my-positions-list',
            properties: {
                employees: {
                    type: Array,
                    value: function() {
                        return [
                            {first: 'Bob', last: 'Smith', country: 'united states'},
                            {first: 'Sally', last: 'Johnson', country: 'united kingdom'}
                        ];
                    }
                }
            },
            attached: function() {
             this.async(function() {
                   console.log(this.$$("#Bob"));
             });
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: Adding a default value is not possible for me because in my application, I actually receive the values through a firebase-collection then I bind them to dom-repeat template. 
A side note, I tried your suggestion and it doesn't work.

Comment: I edited my answer. Code above works for me. Looks like "ready" is not ready enough. Even tho it should fire after the local dom is ready, attached gets the result. You can fill the value with your firebase collection result.

Comment: For me it is still not working. However, If I print 'this', I get 'my-positions-list' node with containing the div ids of Bob and Sally. So I think we are close.

Comment: I read about it, but I did not find an example of how to use it. Do you have a link to a use case?

Comment: @Salah Saleh You might take a look at the utilty function: async(method, [wait])
I get "<div class="style-scope my-positions-list" id="Bob"></div>" as console output, (in your code your Bob got an extra whitespace at the end)
Did you use my code and still got the problem?
I updated the code.

Comment: Yeah, I needed that in a method where data was triggered by an external event. Just wrap the console.log into the async.

Comment: I tried 'async' but still doesn't work for me :s yes I tried your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think that template is constructed in local shadow dom and _dummy is called before it is attached to higher level  dom to be available for querySelector or querySelectorAll.